# Is it ok to remove a laptop battery while the laptop is running on AC power?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are notebook batteries generally hot-swappable?](https://superuser.com/questions/115907/are-notebook-batteries-generally-hot-swappable)

I have a charged laptop battery in a laptop that is running on AC power and charging the battery. Would it damage the battery if I remove it while the computer is running?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/131727/can-you-plug-in-the-battery-while-laptop-is-on-ac-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can remove it. 
No.  It shouldn't damage the battery.

Comment: any source to back this up?