# Can I remove my laptop battery while it's running?

Tags: battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are notebook batteries generally hot-swappable?](https://superuser.com/questions/115907/are-notebook-batteries-generally-hot-swappable)
>   [Is it ok to remove a laptop battery while the laptop is running on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/138128/is-it-ok-to-remove-a-laptop-battery-while-the-laptop-is-running-on-ac-power)

I have an HP laptop and I'm wondering if it will mess anything up if I swap the battery while it's running and plugged in.

Comment: Yes, that's ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it ok to remove a laptop battery while the laptop is running on AC power?](http://superuser.com/questions/138128/is-it-ok-to-remove-a-laptop-battery-while-the-laptop-is-running-on-ac-power) and/or [Are notebook batteries generally hot-swappable?](http://superuser.com/questions/115907/are-notebook-batteries-generally-hot-swappable)

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. The laptop may run in a reduced performance mode while the battery is out, but it should return to normal as soon as the battery is replaced.

Comment: Why would the performance be reduced?

Comment: @wizlog A lot of computers, particularly ones with intel processors, automatically downclock once you're on battery power.

Comment: Although I fail to see why a removed battery, while using AC power, will make it have a lower performance..

Comment: @wizlog The AC adapter supplies power through a long, thin cord with a lot of inductance. The current can't increase quickly enough to compensate for sudden increases in CPU power consumption. To protect against a dangerous drop in voltage, some laptops down-clock the CPU when the battery is removed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz source please.

Comment: @wizlog It makes no sense to respond to an *explanation* with a request for a source. But if you insist on a source, [here's one](http://support.lenovo.com/en_AE/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-71222) and [here's another](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2332).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you very much... I just learned something (+1)!!