# Using a laptop without battery

Tags: ups, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are notebook batteries generally hot-swappable?](https://superuser.com/questions/115907/are-notebook-batteries-generally-hot-swappable)

My battery is at 50% wear and I was planning to use it on AC without the battery.
I was planning to use an on-line UPS so as to avoid spikes , fluctuations and data loss in case of power outage.
Are there other things that need to be taken into consideration while using a laptop without the battery?

Comment: It’s not a duplicate; this is asking if there are any warnings about using a laptop with a UPS.

Comment: It would be reopened to be closed as not constructive for the wide ranging chasm of things to consider @syn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run my laptop without its battery about 80% of the time. I have never had any problems, except for when I accidentally unplugged it. (but thats just me being stupid ;)

I would say you are running a risk by not using the battery: if someone tries to move your laptop and unplugs it unknowingly... you just lost whatever you were working on. But if you are willing to take that risk, you should have not other problems!